# TextToSpeech is giving "Language is not supporting" error in API 23

Tags: java, android

I'm setting up `TextToSpeech` to my app.It's working well on API 26 and above but not working on API 23.It's giving language not supporting error.
My logcat:

```
07-31 16:22:04.872 6935-7000/com.caneraltuner.tarihkitabm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa94e480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaa951d00)
07-31 16:22:04.876 6935-7000/com.caneraltuner.tarihkitabm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa94e480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaa951d00)
07-31 16:22:04.897 6935-7000/com.caneraltuner.tarihkitabm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa94e480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaa951d00)
07-31 16:22:04.906 6935-7000/com.caneraltuner.tarihkitabm D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa94e480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaa951d00)
```

And my codeblock:

```
public void speakOut(View view) {
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
                int result = mTTS.setLanguage(locale);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dil Desteklenmiyor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    mTTS.speak(leaderInfoText.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ses Yüklenemedi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try on real device of that api?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov no i didn't

Comment: try. Something might be wrong with your emulator. Try genymotion and native emulator also